# How to set grid size for resource editor in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a dialog resource in a Visual Studio 2012 C++ project and I want to change the grid size for the editor.  I tried changing Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer -> Default Grid Cell Size, but this does not seem to be the applicable setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is changed from the **Guide Settings** dialog, which you can get to from the **Format** menu that appears when the dialog editor active.